# Forward slash in class name

Tags: html, css, validation

Is it valid to use `/` in a class name in html/css?

```
// html
<div class="/10"></div>

// css
./10{ float:left; }
```

Comment: This will answer it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors

Comment: this symbol is not valid.For reference goto the above posted link..

Comment: Using non-alphanumeric chars in identifiers is always a bad idea no matter what.

Comment: myclass,myclass1,m1yclass are valid,1myclass is not valid.
No symbols should not be added except underscore.

Comment: You need to [escape the character](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#escaped-characters), so it would need to be a blackslash `.\10`

Comment: @Sharath All your examples are perfectly valid, you just can't select the one starting with a number in CSS without escaping the leading character. http://jsfiddle.net/SgzCq/

Comment: Check this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use most [unicode characters](http://css-tricks.com/unicode-class-names/) in both the `class` and `id` attributes in HTML.

This means you can indeed use `/` in a classname in HTML, but you will run into problems when trying to select it with `./10` in CSS, as you've likely found out yourself. If you escape the slash, you're golden! :)

```
.\/10 {
    float:left;
}
```

Check out http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class and http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes